# Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 3000 v2.0 not working, but paired Wireless Mouse 5000 on same receiver does?

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, hardware-failure

I have a Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 3000 v2.0 that was bought paired with a Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000. They're both Bluetooth and use the same receiver.

The keyboard no longer works. The receiver is fine, as the mouse still works. The keyboard is still detected by Windows when the receiver is plugged in. The batteries have been replaced. There are no on/off switches on the keyboard or mouse, and no re-sync button on them or the receiver. Results are the same when using the receiver in a different USB port, or on a different machine.

Anything else I might try to fix this, or should I hold a funeral for the keyboard?

Comment: Update to the [latest drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/wireless-keyboard-3000v2.0). Just the reinstall might fix it. Also check for any stuck keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too  had this same problem with my 3000 keyboard, because the transmitter is a nano transmitter there is no re*syn* capability (no mouse with this keyboard...the keyboard IS available without the mouse combo).

I contacted Microsoft and explained the situation and seeing as the keyboard has a 3 year warranty, they replaced it right there & then, no questions asked. all I had to do was supply them with the model#, serial# and where I purchased the item from.
I was pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Wow did it in under 20 min

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also. In my case, the problem turned out to be the "Turn on repeat and slow keys" setting.

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Set up Filter Keys

Comment: Could you possibly re-work your answer? it reads more like a question than an answer.

Comment: That's where the setting is located.  What should someone do once there?

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the Microsoft wireless keyboard 3000 v2 not working was the battery power indicator not on. the battery contact (especially the spring had corrosion.  I cleaned the contacts installed  the batteries and it works
GC

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem, was about to give up and throw a perfectly good keyboard in the round tin when I found this 'Filter Keys' post.

Well done, it fixed the problem for me with Windows 8.1 on Surface Pro.

On Win8.1, probably similar for Win10.
Go to Settings, Ease of Access, Keyboard ... change the 'Filter Keys' to 'off' 
This setting states it is to 'ignore or slow down brief or repeated keystrokes and adjust keyboard repeat rates' ... immediate result, keyboard was working in 1-2 seconds.
In my case like above the mouse had always worked, the keyboard had been in the cupboard for about a year and I was trying to use it with a new system.